# Embed Google Earth gadget into secure Facebook application

Tags: facebook, google-maps, kml, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to embed the google earth gadget into a secure Facebook application, but I am having some trouble with the google gadgets URL's not being secure,

```
<script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://dl.google.com/developers/maps/embedkmlgadget.xml&amp;up_kml_url=&amp;up_view_mode=earth&amp;up_earth_2d_fallback=1&amp;up_earth_fly_from_space=1&amp;up_earth_show_nav_controls=1&amp;up_earth_show_buildings=1&amp;up_earth_show_terrain=1&amp;up_earth_show_roads=1&amp;up_earth_show_borders=1&amp;up_earth_sphere=earth&amp;up_maps_zoom_out=1&amp;up_maps_default_type=hybrid&amp;synd=open&amp;w=500&amp;h=400&amp;title=Test&amp;border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&amp;output=js"></script>
```

it refuses to load the gadget in a https environment, as it should, but now I can't seem to find any way of generating secure script tags for the gadget, I have googled my butt off and also searched through SO, but I can't find anything helpful, any idea on how I can get this gadget to display in my Facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck serving a gadget, then this answer won't help.  If you can turn your gadget into a served web page instead of a gadget, then there's a simple answer.  The google javascript file that includes Google Earth changes from:

http://www.google.com/jsapi

to

https://www.google.com/jsapi

and you're off and running.